# How to save/export a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table to a shapefile

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, shapefile, postgresql

I want to know how to save/export a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table to a shapefile?
I tried to run the code below the line but unfortunately without success.
How can I do this?

---

```
import qgis.core 
import os
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error

try:
    # Connect to an existing database
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="postgres",
                                  host="localhost",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="Liaisons_C6")

    # Create a cursor to perform database operations
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
        # Executing a SQL query
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM public.draw_liaisons_c6;")
    draw = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM public.draw_liaisons_c6;")       
    path = r'C:/Users/pschitter/Documents/philippe/BE-TELCO_EXTIA_AIX/Marouane/dessin_liaisons_c6/test.shp'
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(draw,path,fileEncoding='utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')
    
except (Exception, Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
    if (connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: And what's wrong with `pgsql2shp - postgis to shapefile dumper`?

Comment: The shapefile format is more than just a little inadequate as an exchange format for data types that support more than 255 fields, filenames in excess of 10 bytes, string fields exceeding 254 bytes, numeric nulls, datetime at higher than day precision, BLOB and CLOB types, tables whose row width exceeds 4000 bytes, and data exceeding 2GiB of storage.

Comment: The problem is my code crashed/shuts down QGIS.
--
(In my company, we have to use the Shapefile only as a format for exchanging and delivering data in accordance with customer requests.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have QGIS installed then you also have the very powerful command line tool [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) available which is part of [gdal](https://gdal.org/) library that is included in the QGIS installation.

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:/gis/kunnat.shp" "PG:dbname=gis host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres" kunnat
```

If you want to code this with python then you can write the equivalent as:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.UseExceptions()

try:
    ds = gdal.VectorTranslate(
        destNameOrDestDS="C:/gis/kunnat.shp",
        srcDS="PG:dbname=gis host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres",
        format="ESRI Shapefile",
        layers=["kunnat"],
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Translation failed: {e}")
```

Using gdal is also much faster than using QgsVectorFileWriter.